# Angular Grunt lazyloading app concating

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, concatenation

I am making an angular app and using lazyloading for loading controllers and services.
I am loading controller and services js file only when they are required using

e.g.
"resolve" option of ui-routing.

```
.state('app.login', {
        url: 'login/signin',
        title: 'Login',
        resolve: loadSequence('LoginController'),
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'assets/views/login_login.html',
                //controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        }
    })
```

loadSequence have the logic to load logincontroller.js

Now for deployment i need to concat my js file.
I am aware of grunt concatenate task.
If i concat all js files in single file my lazyloading will be destroyed.

Can anyone plz suggest me how to get this requirement with lazyload to work along.

Thanks

Comment: Is it like you are using `requireJS` in your `loadSequence()` ? I had a project where there is JS concat for "initial" state. And lazy load (load on demand) for further page/controller. And this project is a combine of `angular`, `ui-route`, `angularAMD` and `requireJS`. (JS concat will be handled by `requireJS` compiler named `r.js`)

Comment: Thanks Vishwanath, I am using ocLazyLoad for loading my services and controller.Cant find anything in that.Can you help me with an example.Thanks in advance